# Neo4j Cypher: exclude certain nodes from result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two queries, call them query A and query B. What I need is to get all the results of query A that are not in query B. Example:

Query A:

```
MATCH (m:MyNode {prop: 'value'}), (n:MyNode {prop: 'value', otherProp: (m).otherProp}
  WHERE m<>n AND shortestPath( (m)-[*]-(n) ) IS NULL
  RETURN m
```

Query B:

```
MATCH (m:MyNode)-[:SOME_RELATION]->()<-[:SOME_RELATION]-(n:MyNode {prop: 'value'})
    WHERE m.prop<>'value'
    RETURN n
```

These two queries return what I expect, but what I really want is everything that Query A returns that Query B does not.

I've tried a bunch of different things mostly using WHERE NONE based on what I found at https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/performing-pattern-negation/, but all I seem to be able to do is eliminate all of the results instead of just those that come from Query B.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, after asking, I found my own solution. Here's what I came up with:

```
Match (r:MyNode)-[:SOME_RELATION]->()<-[:SOME_RELATION]-(s:MyNode { prop: 'value' })
    WHERE r.prop<>'value'
    WITH COLLECT(s) AS excluded
MATCH (m:MyNode {prop: 'value'}), (n:MyNode {prop: 'value', otherProp: (m).otherProp})
    WITH excluded, COLLECT(m) AS included
RETURN FILTER(n IN included WHERE NOT n IN EXCLUDED)
```

This works for me, but I'm certainly open to more efficient solutions if anyone has one.