# Neo4j Cypher: Filtering a query results based on another query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find a list of names that unique to one query and exclude the ones that are common between the results of two queries. For example, I want the name of the classes that have been taken by students A, B, and C. And exclude from this list the classes that were taken by students D and E. With the help of the answer to this question ([Neo4j Cypher: exclude certain nodes from result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59397418/neo4j-cypher-exclude-certain-nodes-from-result/65904934#65904934)), I tried this Cypher code and it works, but I get the results as nodes. I want it as a list of names, not nodes.

```
Match (m:class)-[r]-(n:student) where n.name in ['aa','bb','cc']    
WITH COLLECT(m) AS EXCLUDED
MATCH  (m1:class)-[r1]-(n1:student) where n1.name in ['dd','ee'] 
WITH EXCLUDED, COLLECT(m1) AS included
RETURN FILTER(m1 IN included WHERE NOT m1 IN EXCLUDED)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have another `WITH` and `UNWIND`.

```
Match (m:class)-[r]-(n:student) where n.name in ['aa','bb','cc']    
WITH COLLECT(m) AS EXCLUDED
MATCH  (m1:class)-[r1]-(n1:student) where n1.name in ['dd','ee'] 
WITH EXCLUDED, COLLECT(m1) AS included
WITH FILTER(m1 IN included WHERE NOT m1 IN EXCLUDED) as _results
UNWIND _results as results
RETURN results.name
```

**Note:** `FILTER()` is deprecated in neo4j 3.5 and removed in 4.0 in favor of [List Comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension)

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. I am sorry I can not upvote your answer because I am new here and they do not allow me to do that, but I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I have a question please, I am trying to get the names of the students and the type of the relationships for the result classes. I did that:
(The same 5 lines then the following)
"UNWIND _results as results 
MATCH  (n1:students)-[r1]-(m1:class{name:results.name}) where n1.name in ['dd','ee'] 
RETURN distinct results.name as ClassName, n1.name as StudentName,  type(r1) as RelType"
This works, but it queries the graph again. Is there a more efficient way to avoid query the graph again?

Comment: @AlLearner Since the original post is addressed it is better to open it as a new question, larger audience will take a look at it and you can hear better solutions from people.

Comment: @AlLearner But I beleive you need to redo the query since the second query structure is different or may be you can directly collect the results you want in second match statment instead of having a filter and redoing the query.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I will try to solve it. If I do not find a way, I will open a new question. Thanks again :)